# Is there any method to know which enviroment variables is trying to read a linux program?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to install a software in Ubuntu 20.04. When running the setup, an error occurs because it's trying to write a log file in root folder.

This error was not present when I installed the same program in Ubuntu 16.04. Even, without running it as root.

I suspect that the installation program is trying to read some enviroment variable that not longer exists in this version, and it's trying to locate the log files in root folder by default.

Is there any method to know which enviroment variables is trying to read a binary file?

Comment: Do you have the source code of the setup program?  You'll probably find the answer faster by reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `strace`, it will tell you all calls to OS.

Comment: Reading an environment variable isn't a system call, though.  The whole environment is passed to the program when it is exec'ed.  Functions like `getenv()` operate entirely in user space, and the program can even parse the environment without any library call by accessing the `environ` global variable or the third argument to `main`.